# Make background image stop at div line

Tags: css

I have a background image inserted into my page, using this code.

```
<style>
#bodypage
{
background-image:url('image');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:bottom right; 
}
</style>
```

However, the image is cut off by a div, upon scrolling to the bottom of the page

[image]

Ideally, the bottom of the image should stop right at that line, (which is a new div), instead of scrolling underneath it.

How can I accomplish this?

For further clarification

I would like that image to remain stopped at the line, without getting cut off, rather than have that line cut it off, as shown here.

[image]

Comment: What did you try to link to? Anyway, it didn't work...

Comment: did you try `background-size : 100% 100%;` ?

Comment: mohkhan.
The final result should look like this, when I am scrolled to the bottom of the page.
http://puu.sh/3x0fs.jpg
I was able to take that picture by scrolling up.
I would like that image to remain stopped at the line, without getting cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it `background: #000000 url(../path/to/images/img.jpg) no-repeat bottom 0;`